# Multiprocessing with resource contraint

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have **4** GPUs, and say I will spawn total of **100** processes, and **each process** will consume **1 GPU**. The process will be able run to run if there is an empty GPU for it. A finished process will free up the GPU to be used by another process. Here's a partial try:

```
def worker(procnum,gpus):
    #how to only allow the process to come in when there is available gpus?
    print(procnum)
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
gpus = manager.list(range(4))
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
jobs = []
for i in range(100):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,gpus))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()

for proc in jobs:
    proc.join()

print(gpus)
```

What is a good way to achieve what I mentioned? (not limited to the code above, its just a reference)

Comment: Why not just start only up to 4 processes? Say, via a ``multiprocessing.Pool``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi How should I launch say 100 processes and use it with `multiprocessing.Pool`, which I supposed to have a pool of processes of 4?

Comment: Well, why would you *want* to launch 100 process when only 4 of them can do anything? Genuinely asking, since the requirements are totally unclear to me – and affect how to best approach this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Since I have 100 tasks queing, and only have four GPUs (you can thing of it as a resource, and each task needs 1 resource). So at one time there are only four tasks that are running using different resources.

Comment: You are explaining why you want to process 100 tasks, running at most 4 concurrently. You are not explaining why you want to process 100 tasks, running all concurrently but pausing all but 4.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi no need to pause all, we just don't need to run the rest of 96, unless the resources are free up.